# Randomly directed to the bottom of the page instead of the correct post/comment

Tags: bug, mobile-web

The issue only started occurring recently.

Usually, when clicking on a link to a specific answer/comment, the new page automatically scrolls to a position where the answer/comment is shown at the top of the visible screen. However it recently started going all the way down and directly present me with the bottom of the page.

I have not found a stable way to reproduce the problem, but I promise it is there. It confused me for quite a while, and made me hesitate for another while before posting this question here. In general it has a higher chance to occur on comments, and on a significantly higher chance on links where another link to another item on the same page has this issue.

It occurred on two of my Android phones running A 5.1 and A 7.1, Google Chrome 52, 58 and 64 (all from Play store), so I guess it's not my fault.

Comment: I can 100% reproduce both on mobile and desktop views if I click such comment/answer link, scrolling to the bottom, then reload the page. Instead of having the comment focused, the browser will scroll down again to where it was before reloading. This is browser behavior though, not SE bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, but I mean opening the link, not refreshing the page.

Comment: Fair enough, no repro then. :/